# Remove "British-English" in Virtual Keyboard QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtvirtualkeyboard

How to remove "British-English" which is in the spacebar? Please refer below image.

[image]

[Update 1]:

Following is the code that i am using for input panel:

```
 InputPanel {
    id: inputPanel
    parent:mainWindow.contentItem
    z: 1000002
    anchors.bottom:parent.bottom
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right

    visible: Qt.inputMethod.visible
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to make a [custom style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/technical-guide.html#adding-custom-styles) where you override the [`spaceKeyPanel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-virtualkeyboard-styles-keyboardstyle.html#spaceKeyPanel-prop). For example, adapting the [default style's `spaceKeyPanel`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard.git/tree/src/virtualkeyboard/content/styles/default/style.qml#n428):

```
spaceKeyPanel: KeyPanel {
    Rectangle {
        id: spaceKeyBackground
        radius: 5
        color: "#35322f"
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: keyBackgroundMargin
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using input panel in my code please check for "update 1" tag in the Question. How to add the styles for that ?. Because there is no style attribute for input panel and please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Did you read the "custom style" documentation that I linked to? That page explains how to add a custom style to your application. Alternatively, if you don't want to add a whole new style and you don't mind modifying Qt's source code, you could just remove the `Text` item from the default style and rebuild the module.

Comment: I read the doc, But i was thinking that there is an easy way to directly add the style to input panel. Thanks, i will rebuild the module by removing the `Text` item.